# Are 2011 Apple Macs EFI-ready for Boot Camp?

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp, efi

I would like to know if the most recent Apple Macs have the EFI firmware up to date to boot Windows through Boot Camp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? *Any* Intel-based Mac can use Boot Camp to install and boot Windows. Only really early Intel-based Macs needed an EFI firmware upgrade.

The only restrictions (currently) are: Boot Camp 4.0 can't boot Windows XP and Vista, and it can't be used on Macs using a Mac Pro RAID card or software RAID.

See more on the [Apple Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) support site.